# How can I grab all the content/text on a page inside a protractor test?

Tags: angularjs, testing, jasmine, protractor

I want to set a variable based on whether some text is present on the current page or not.

And then run a `protractor` test that depends on that variable. I can't do `$(':contains')` because there's `$ != jQuery` in this context and i can't see a simple way to do it with `getText()` which returns a promise. Is there a matcher like `expect.toContain`? and a way to run some code after that matcher is run? Or is there some other strategy i can use.

Answer (score 0):

if i think i understand you correctly you could use these following lines :

this will give all the text from the page :

```
window.document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].innerText
```

and then you could use a regex to check for your text like this :

```
var res = patt.test(str);
```

this is sort of what you get :

for this example i am searching for the text "status": "ok"

```
var str = window.document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].innerText;
var patt = /"status": "ok"/;
var res = patt.test(str);
if(res){console.log(text is present!)}
```

Comment: is window available inside the protractor test context?

Comment: i use it in combination with browser.executeScript

Answer (score 0):

you want something a bit like this:

```
 // utility to test expection of an element to match a regex:   
 var expectByCssToMatch = function(css, pattern) {             
   browser.driver.findElement(                                  
     by.css(css)).getText().then(function(text) {               
       expect(text).toMatch(pattern);                           
     });                                                        
 };
```

usage:

```
 describe('Logging in, function() {                       
   it('should work', function() {                                           
     var namePattern = new RegExp(param.name, i');
     expectByCssToMatch('.messages', /log\s?in successful/i);        
     expectByCssToMatch('body', namePattern);                       
   });                                                                      
 });
```

to achieve what you're asking you'd want to replace the `expect()` call with a callback of your own choice